# Issues with creating objects of classes in Python

Tags: python, class, pygame

I am trying to make a sword appear when I press the space bar and disappear when I hit key 5.

```
if event.type == pg.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                    self.quit()
                if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                    self.sword = Sword(self, self.player.rect.centerx-7, self.player.rect.bottom, self.player)
                if event.key == pg.K_5:
                    self.sword.kill()
```

I can make the first sword appear and disappear without any issue, but when I try to press the spacebar again, I get this error message:

```
File "/Users/(User)/Desktop/ZeldaGame/sprites.py", line 183, in __init__
    self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
AttributeError: 'Sword' object has no attribute 'set_colorkey'
```

Here is my Sword class:

```
class Sword(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y, entity):
        self.groups = game.all_sprites
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.game = game
        self.image = self.game.sword
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.rect.x = x 
        self.rect.y = y 
        if entity.direction == 'down':
            self.image = pg.transform.rotate(self.image, -90)

        def update(self):
            kill()
```

Could anyone help me make the sword able to appear, disappear, and appear over and over again?

Comment: What exactly does `Sword.kill` do? It appears to be trying to call `self.set_colorkey` rather than `self.image.set_colorkey`.

Comment: @chepner sword.kill() is a builtin function of pg.sprite.Sprite, it removes the sprite from the sprite group game.all_sprites. I am blitting all the sprites in game.all_sprites, so when I remove it with sword.kill(), it stops being blit onto the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Warning: I don't know anything about PyGame.

It seems as if `game.sword` initially, before the very first sword is created, is a `pygame.Surface` object - This is just a guess, because you didn't show that part of the code. (`set_colorkey` seems to be a `pygame.Surface` method, and by virtue of the fact that you can invoke `Sword.__init__` the first time without any errors tells me that `game.sword` must initially be a `pygame.Surface` object, otherwise `self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)` would raise an error).

Then, the second time you press the spacebar, `game.sword` will be refering to a `Sword` object, since you executed `self.sword = Sword(...` the first time you pressed the spacebar. You enter the second sword's `__init__`, but now `game.sword` refers to a `Sword`, not a `pygame.Surface`. `Sword`s don't have a `set_colorkey` method, hence the error (I'm guessing `pygame.Sprite` does not inherit from `pygame.Surface`).